# Detecting if a type can be derived from in C++

Tags: c++, sfinae, template-meta-programming

I have the following template class and a (global) variable of its type:

```
template <typename ClassT>
struct ClassTester : public ClassT {
    typedef ClassT type;
};

ClassTester<int> *aaa;  // No error here
```

I would expect a compilation error because `int` cannot be derived from, but this compiles fine under Visual C++ 2010.

If I remove the pointer, I get the expected compilation error (int cannot be derived from):

```
ClassTester<int> bbb; // Error here
```

I wanted to use this class for SFINAE testing whether the given type is a class that can be derived from:

```
template <typename T>
struct CanBeDerivedFrom  {

    template <typename C>
    static int test(ClassTester<T> *) { }

    template <typename>
    static char test(...) { }

    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(int));
};
```

This, however, always reports true, even for primitive types such as `int` because of the above reason. Is this an expected/valid behavior of C++?

Comment: I suspect the reason is that simply declaring/defining a pointer does not require actually instantiating the template. After all, you don't use that `ClassTester<int>*` for anything.

Comment: A similar example would be checking whether a template parameter is POD or non POD.

Comment: I was going to suggest as visitor had. I don't believe declaring a pointer will instantiate the template, which is why it may compile. Try accessing a member using the template via the pointer, which would force the compiler to instantiate the template. Otherwise, I'm not too sure - but I know that you can't inherit an integer type.

Comment: @Jeremy: Then it gives a compiler error that the class cannot derive from int. That's also weird, I thought SFINAE would just reject that overload and not throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's **not possible** entirely to get a `class` which is derivable through SFINAE (which includes also the cases of `final class` in C++11). The best thing which can be done is to have a SFINAE for finding if a type is a `class` and rely upon that.

```
template<typename T>
struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct CanBeDerivedFrom {
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct CanBeDerivedFrom<T, typename void_<int T::*>::type> {
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

This metaprogram will find if the given type is `class/union` or not. [demo](http://www.ideone.com/LkLsw).

Comment: Even though it's not 100% the answer, it's definitely an interesting approach.

Answer (score 4):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use boost::is_class
[boost reference manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_class.html)

Those guys known better than you do.

Comment: boost::is_class does a bit different thing - it tests whether the given type is a class. I want to test whether the type can be derived from. These two are not the same in the new C++11 standard. And I haven't found any Boost type trait that would help me achieve this.

Comment: I don't think he meant for it to be rude. Hes saying that BOOST has done their research in the sort of thing for a while so you're better off using boost:is_class or at least taking a look at how it was implemented.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude. You can make a class not derivable through various techniques, such as this one [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.11) that is surely not detectable until you try to instantiate a variable of a derived class if you do not specify a ctor in the derived class (and wait for the compiler to autogenerate one and emit an error). boost::is_class is surely the simpler, more portable way to achieve something near it. See comments about clang and final in this thread too.

Comment: When I come to read about something I'd like to understand, being told to just use someone else's solution 'cause they know better is quite offensive. I realize that wasn't your intent, however I very much dislike this form of "answer".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think that this is actually impossible.

Many issues may prevent derivation (or at least, useful derivation), the addition of `final` to the standard being one.

For example, see [this thread](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/http-llvm-org-bugs-show-bug-cgi-id-11462-td3555541.html) on the Clang mailing list where Howard Hinnant requires a compiler intrinsic to check whether the class is marked as `final` or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest as visitor had. I don't believe declaring a pointer will instantiate the template, which is why it may compile. Try accessing a member using the template via the pointer, which would force the compiler to instantiate the template. Otherwise, I'm not too sure - but I know that you can't inherit an integer type.

So, the answer I suppose would be you don't need to, as the code probably won't compile in the event that you do try to instantiate a template class inheriting an integer type. I may be wrong, but I believe the only reason it is compiling is because creating a pointer type does not instantiate the template.

Comment: If I try accessing the pointer it gives a compiler error that the class cannot derive from int. That's also weird, I thought SFINAE would just reject that overload and not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTTI(Run Time Type Information) to know what type the class belongs to , and if the class is of basic type you can tell that the class cannot be derived from.

Ex:
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(int) || typeid(T) == typeid(float))
    {
        cout << "The class cannot be derived from";
    }

You can add more types if you want , to the IF condition

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need this at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

```
main()
{
 int i;
 int * pi;
 cout << int is:  << typeid(int).name() << endl;
 cout <<   i is: << typeid(i).name() << endl;
 cout <<  pi is:  << typeid(pi).name() << endl;
 cout << *pi is:  << typeid(*pi).name() << endl << endl;
```

}

it prints:

```
int
int
int*
int
```

as expected..

someone needs to be indipendent of other library...so boost library it s not a good answer..